# Ruby: how can use the dump method to output data to a csv file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I try to use the ruby standard csv lib to dump out the arr of object to a csv.file , called 'a.csv'

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-dump

```
dump(ary_of_objs, io = "", options = Hash.new)
```

but in this method, how can i dump into a file?
there is no such examples exists and help. I google it no example to do for me...

Also, the docs said that...

> The next method you can provide is an instance method called
>   csv_headers(). This method is expected to return the second line of
>   the document (again as an Array), which is to be used to give each
>   column a header. By default, ::load will set an instance variable if
>   the field header starts with an @ character or call send() passing the
>   header as the method name and the field value as an argument. This
>   method is only called on the first object of the Array.

Anyone knows how to pass the instance method csv_headers() to this dump function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this out yet, but it looks like io should be set to a file.  According to the doc you linked "The io parameter can be used to serialize to a File"

Something like:
`f = File.open("filename")

dump(ary_of_objs, io = f, options = Hash.new)`

Comment: It works, but do u know how to pass the instance method to that method?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't really answer the question so I thought I'd give a useful example.

First of all if you look at the docs at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html, if you hover over the method name for `dump` you see you can `click to show source`.  If you do that you'll see that the `dump` method attempts to call `csv_headers` on the first object you pass in from `ary_of_objs`:

```
obj_template = ary_of_objs.first

...snip...

headers = obj_template.csv_headers
```

Then later you see that the method will call `csv_dump` on each object in `ary_of_objs` and pass in the `headers`:

```
ary_of_objs.each do |obj|
    begin
      csv << obj.csv_dump(headers)
    rescue NoMethodError
      csv << headers.map do |var|
        if var[0] == @
          obj.instance_variable_get(var)
        else
          obj[var[0..-2]]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

So we need to augment each entry in `array_of_objs` to respond to those two methods.  Here's an example wrapper class that would take a `Hash`, and return the hash keys as the CSV headers and then be able to dump each row based on the headers.

```
class CsvRowDump               
  def initialize(row_hash)     
    @row = row_hash            
  end                                                  

  def csv_headers              
    @row.keys                  
  end                          

  def csv_dump(headers)        
    headers.map { |h| @row[h] }
  end                          
end
```

There's one more catch though.  This `dump` method wants to write an extra line at the top of the CSV file before the headers, and there's no way to skip that if you call this method due to this code at the top:

```
  # write meta information
  begin
    csv << obj_template.class.csv_meta
  rescue NoMethodError
    csv << [:class, obj_template.class]
  end
```

Even if you return '' from `CsvRowDump.csv_meta` that will still be a blank line where a parse expects the headers.  So instead lets let `dump` write that line and then remove it afterwards when we call `dump`.  This example assumes you have an array of hashes that all have the same keys (which will be the CSV header).

```
@rows = @hashes.map { |h| CsvRowDump.new(h) }
File.open(@filename, "wb") do |f|
  str = CSV::dump(@rows)
  f.write(str.split(/\n/)[1..-1].join("\n"))
end
```