# How do I serialize data and write it into a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, serialization, csv

I have a bunch of data that needs to be written into a CSV file. Currently I'm doing this:

```
CSV.open("file.csv" , 'w' ) do |writer|
   readfromCSV.each do |x|
     writer << x
   end
end
```

I need to serialize all the data and write it into the CSV file.

I'm new to serialization, I read about `Marshal.dump(x)` which serializes the array, but it throws an error when I try to do `writer<<x`.

I read about the option `dump(ary_of_objs, io = "", options = Hash.new)`, but could not understand how to implement it in this case.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844669/ruby-how-can-use-the-dump-method-to-output-data-to-a-csv-file

Comment: I did the below to write marshalled data. It wrote without showing any error:   File.open("csvfile.csv" , 'w' ) do |f|
  readfromCSV.each_with_index do |x, i|
Marshal.dump(x, f)
  end
  end

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is `readfromCSV`? We can't help you much if you don't show us the code. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: readfromCSV is just CSV.read("csvFile.csv"). I need to read that file in, makes some changes to that data, serialize it and then write back to it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html explains the functions in the csv module.

say you want to make the first column string in the csv lowercase;

```
CSV.open("file.csv" , 'w' ) do |writer|
   readfromCSV.each do |row|
     # row is a csv row, pretty much an array
     row[0] = row[0].downcase
     writer << row
     #alternatively, you could do it manually eg. writer << ["this", "rocks"]
   end
end
```